# Trying to find all of the objects in my scene by a custom tag script I have created, however i continue getting a null reference exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The Tag script has been working for me so far as an alternate to the unity tags up to this point, allowing me to assign multiple tags to an object at once. Now I want to create a method that will get all of the objects in the scene, filter them by the tag, and then return it as an array. The null reference exception refers to line 41 of the Tag.cs script. How do I fix this?

Tags.cs file

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tags : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string[] startTags;
    private string[] tags;

    private void Start()
    {
        tags = startTags;
    }

    public bool FindTag(string search)
    {
        bool results = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.Length; i++)
        {
            if(search == tags[i])
            {
                results = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    //Find objects by custom script tags
    //HERE IS WHERE THE METHOD IS CREATED
    public static GameObject[] ObjectsByTag(string search)
    {
        //Get all objects in scene
        GameObject[] allObjects = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();
        GameObject[] storedObjects = new GameObject[allObjects.Length];
        GameObject[] finalObjects;

        //Filter
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < allObjects.Length; i++)
        {
            if (allObjects[i].GetComponent<Tags>().FindTag(search)) //line 41
            {
                storedObjects[count] = allObjects[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
        //Assign final length
        finalObjects = new GameObject[count];

        //Reassign to final array
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            finalObjects[i] = storedObjects[i];
        }

        return finalObjects;
    }
}
```

GameController.cs file (How it is being used

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //SCREEN START
    //Get Screen Size
    private float sHeight;
    private float sWidth;

    //Intended Screen Size
    readonly float iH = 695f;
    readonly float iW = 1540f;

    //Convert
    private float cH;
    private float cW;

    public float ConvertedHeight => cH;
    public float ConvertedWidth => cW;
    //SCREEN END

    //MOUSE CAM START
    //mousePostion
    private float mX;
    private float mZ;

    public float MouseX => mX;
    public float MouseZ => mZ;
    //MOUSE CAM END

    //EnemySpeedModifier
    private float esm;
    public float ESM
    {
        get { return esm; }
        set { esm = value; }
    }

    //GameOver
    private bool gameOver = false;
    public bool GameOver
    {
        get { return gameOver; }
        set { gameOver = value; }
    }

    //game speed
    public float speed;

    /*
    //projectile list
    private GameObject[] projectiles;

    public GameObject[] Projectiles()
    {
        return projectiles;
    }
    public void Projectiles(GameObject value)
    {
        GameObject[] tempArray = projectiles;
        tempArray[projectiles.Length] = value;
        projectiles = tempArray;

        Debug.Log("Projectile Count: " + projectiles.Length);
    }
    */
    //HERE IS WHERE IT IS USED
    public GameObject[] ProjectilesInScene
    {
        get
        {
            return Tags.ObjectsByTag("projectile");
        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //CONVERT SCREEN SIZES START
        sHeight = Screen.height;
        sWidth = Screen.width;

        cH = iH / sHeight;
        cW = iW / sWidth;
        //CONVERT SCREEN SIZES END
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (gameOver)
        {
            speed /= 1 + 0.5f * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        //Update mose position
        mX = Input.mousePosition.x;
        mZ = Input.mousePosition.y;
    }
}
```

Comment: allObjects[i].GetComponent<Tags>() ... does this come back null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that not all of your `GameObject` objects have the `Tags` component. Per the [GameObject.GetComponent documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

> Returns the component of Type type if the game object has one attached, null if it doesn't.

If you know that some objects won't have the `Tags` component, your line 41 can use a simple [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators):

```c#
if (allObjects[i].GetComponent<Tags>()?.FindTag(search) == true)
{
    ...
}
```

Note the `?` after `GetComponent<Tags>()`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, I'll try that out.